# first and last bars on matplotlib histogram appear moved

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to create a histogram using these values:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

The code I'm using is this

```
plt.hist(values, histtype='bar', color='green', alpha=0.5)
plt.title(library_name, fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel(xlabel)
plt.ylabel(ylabel)
x1, x2, y1, y2 = plt.axis()
plt.axis((x1-0.5, x2+0.5, y1, y2+0.05))
plt.savefig("../results/histograms/" + library_name)
```

And I get this histogram [image: histogram with first and last bars poorly located]

Does anyone know why are the first and last bars looks aside from their xtick? I tried using plt.margins function with no results.

Thank you very much

Comment: matplotlib binning is very automatic and careless about what you intend. By default, it creates 10 bins between the min and max values. So, in many cases you have to manually specify the bins (as in Samuel Bancroft's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get centre-aligned bins instead of left-aligned, use `plt.hist(data, bins=np.arange(50)-0.5)`

Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

values = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2,5,3,2,5, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1,7,8,9,9,3,8,6, 2]

offset = 0.5

plt.hist(values,  bins=np.arange(1,np.max(values)+2)-offset, histtype='bar', color='green', alpha=0.5)
plt.title('library_name', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
x1, x2, y1, y2 = plt.axis()
plt.axis((x1-0.5, x2+0.5, y1, y2+0.05))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @Samuel Bancroft. is there a way to do that without specifying a constant maximum value of bars in the histogram (in this example 7)? I want it to be as generic as possible.

Comment: No problem. I've updated the code to make it more generic for you. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, you can use [**DISCLAIMER: I wrote it**] the "physt" library which has a couple of binning options including one suitable for integers - see https://github.com/janpipek/physt, and particularly for your case http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/janpipek/physt/blob/master/doc/Binning.ipynb#Integer-binning.

The code be the following:

```
import physt
h = physt.histogram(values, "integer")
ax = h.plot(color="green", alpha=0.5, ticks="center")
```

...and then add your axis/plt formatting...

Comment: Thanks, Looks great